# How to stop if-else statement loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I have this code

```
// If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
if(data == "") { 

    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);                   

} else {

    // Offset increases
    offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

    // Append the data to the content div
    $this.find('#content_ins_con_all_posts').append(data);

    // No longer busy!  
    busy = false;
}
```

This code displays me a message when hit the bottom and there is no other posts to show. My problem is that when I continue scrolling, the message continue showing again and again multiple times... I just want to show me the message only one time when the posts ends. If there is a way in how I can do that is most welcome.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

    var settings = { 
        nop     : 3, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
        offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
        error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                    // displayed. You can change this if you want.
        delay   : 2000, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                       // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
        scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                       // but will still load if the user clicks.
    }

    // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    // For each so that we keep chainability.
    return this.each(function() {       

        // Some variables 
        $this = $(this);
        $settings = settings;
        var offset = $settings.offset;
        var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                          // so we don't run it multiple times

        // Custom messages based on settings
        if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = 'Scroll for more or click here';
        else $initmessage = 'Click for more';

        // Append custom messages and extra UI
        $this.append('<div id="content_ins_con_all_posts"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

        function getData() {

            // Post data to ajax.php
            $.post('functions_index_result_all_img.php', {

                action        : 'scrollpagination',
                number        : $settings.nop,
                offset        : offset,

            }, function(data) {

                // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);

                // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error

                if(data == "") { 
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);                   

                } 
                else {  
                    // Offset increases
                    offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                    // Append the data to the content div
                    $this.find('#content_ins_con_all_posts').append(data);

                    // No longer busy!  
                    busy = false;

                }

            });

        }   

        getData(); // Run function initially

        // If scrolling is enabled
        if($settings.scroll == true) {
            // .. and the user is scrolling
            $(window).scroll(function() {

                // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {

                    // Now we are working, so busy is true
                    busy = true;

                    // Tell the user we're loading posts
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html('Loading Posts');

                    // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
                    // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
                    // want the user to see.
                    setTimeout(function() {

                        getData();

                    }, $settings.delay);

                }   
            });
        }

        // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
        $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {

            if(busy == false) {
                busy = true;
                getData();
            }

        });

    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That code shouldn't loop, it must be something else in your code calling it repeatedly.

Comment: Set global variable where you store value if the bottom has been hit. Every time you load new data you set that variable to false. In if statement you compare to that variable, and if it's false, you execute the code, if it's true you don't.

Comment: this code is not enough!

Answer (score 3):

Two ways off the top of my head

1. check where the cursor is, if it is near a certain range from the bottom do not trigger that code
2. store a flag in the sessionStorage or in a variable (depending on your code) which mean that you already showed the message, remove the flag once the cursor moves away from the bottom past a certain distance you defined.

Comment: +1, but for the 2nd approach you might have to reset the flag (when stored in session), when leaving and reentering the page. (depending on your design.

Answer (score 1):

You may set a flag in your code. Something like:

```
// If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
if(data == "") { 

    if(!flag) {
        $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);
        flag = true; // You need to declare flag = false at an appropriate place in your code.
    }
} else {

    // Offset increases
    offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

    // Append the data to the content div
    $this.find('#content_ins_con_all_posts').append(data);

    // No longer busy!  
    busy = false;

}
```

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global var to know if you have to display the message

Something like this :

```
var isDisplayed = false;
```

then

```
if (isDisplayed == false)
{
   isDisplayed = true;
   displayMessage();
}
```